# File input to gnuplot through python

Tags: python, mysql, gnuplot

I am trying to draw a graph of some data I pull out of a MySQL database through python with gnuplot and gnuplot.py.
I read the latest 10 lines of data from the MySQL database and store them in a temp file which is supposed to be read by gnuplot. I can do this the manual way by setting through the terminal, but I simply can't see how I should load the file into gnuplot through python.
If you can show me an easier way to do this, or simply a way to do it at all, I would be very grateful.

```
import MySQLdb
import Gnuplot

datafile = open('data', 'w+r')

gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(persist=1)
gp('set style data lines')
gp('set term png')
gp('set output "escan_graph.png"')
gp('set datafile separator "|"')

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="password", db="zig")
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from escan_data")

numrows = int(cursor.rowcount) #get the count of total
# get and display one row at a time

if numrows > 10:
        start = numrows-10
else:
        start = 0

for x in range(start,numrows):
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        print row[0], row[1]
        datafile.write(str(row[0]) + "|" + str(row[1]) + "\n")



databuff = Gnuplot.Data(datafile.read(), title="test")


gp.plot(databuff)
```

row[0] is the x-axis and row[1] is y-axis.

Comment: Why are you writing the data to a file and then immediately reading it back in again?  Why not save your x and y data to arrays and then provide those to gnuplot?

Comment: Oh dear, why didn't I think of that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because after you `write` the file object's cursor is at the end of the file. If you want to really do this (you are better off not writing the data to a file at all), you need to move the cursor back to the beginning of the file:

```
datafile.seek(0)
```

Now you can `read()` from the beginning of the file.

Comment: I guess you actually answered my question even though it was a very inefficient method to do it. Though I will still rate your answer as the solution even though I ended up using arrays. Thank you.

Comment: @drblah For sure. I noticed in comments the in-efficiency was pointed out, however I assumed you'd still want to know WHY it wasn't working.